# Why FindOneAndUpdate is not working in mongoose when using $in

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to run the following query to update one of my collections but it is not working

```
    const result = await users.findOneAndUpdate({
    participants: {
        "$in": [participant.one, participant.two]
    },
    time:Date.now()


   });
   console.log(result, " result ")
```

I am getting the following error

```
 Cast to [string] failed for value "[{"$in":["****","****"]}]" at path "participants"
```

Comment: I wonder why the error message surrounds your object with `[]`

Comment: because participants is an array

Comment: it wrapped the entire object including `$in` in an array, that seems odd.

Comment: @Ahmed : Did you check what these `participant.one, participant.two` are printed ?

Comment: @whoami yup and they are the correct filtering values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`participants` is an array and so you should use [array query operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query-array/).

If you want to filter the documents for which the `participants` array contains all the given elements, use

```
participants: {
    "$all": [participant.one, participant.two]
},
```